# which is indicated" vs. "is indicated

Tags: passive-voice, be, which-what

The question is about the use of:

- which is indicated

and

- is indicated

Examples:

1. Visible need in this area, **which is indicated** by the number of articles and books on the subject.

1a. Visible need in this area, **which is indicated** by the number of articles and books on the subject, like those written by Hillary Dane, describing the use of high speed particles.

2. Visible need in this area **is indicated** by the number of articles and books on the subject.

Do you see the difference and what the difference is in your opinion between these two sentences?

Are these sentences properly formulated? What would the proper sentence look like when "which is" in use?

Answer (score 1):

(2) is a simple statement.

In (1), the part after the comma is a subordinate clause describing *need*. It isn't a complete sentence unless you go on to say something more about the 'visible need'.

Compare: *My friend John, whom I have known since childhood,...*

Comment: Thanks.Please check the example 1a. Would it make any better?

Comment: No, because the additional phrases describe the _articles and books_, not the _visible need_.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example [S: Visible need in this area + non-defining relative clause: which is indicated by the number of articles and books on the subject] is a sentence fragment, not a sentence: there is no verb related to the subject. Only the second example is a complete sentence [S: Visible need in this area; V:is indicated; Adverb of agent: by the number of articles and books on the subject]